# Doctrine2 complex multiple many-to-many search query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, dql

I am creating an application that has an Entity that has multiple many-to-many relationships with other objects. Let me layout the Entities:

- Entry = the main object
- Region = has many-to-many with Entry via "_entry_region" reference table
- Type = has many-to-many with Entry via "_entry_type" reference table
- Tag = has many-to-many with Entry via "_entry_tag" reference table

Now in the frontend the user can setup some filters for the entries that need to be loaded. In human language the query needs to be like this.

```
Get the entries WHERE  region is (1 or 2 or 3) AND type is ( 3 or 4 or 5 ) AND tag is ( 4 OR 6 or 1)
```

i currently strugle with this piece of code:

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT m.id FROM Entity\Entry e WHERE :region_id MEMBER OF e.regions);
$query->setParameter('region_id',  1);      
$ids = $query->getResult();
```

This gives me the ID's of the entry's of the corresponding region. but it is not possible to add an array of the region id's in the setParameter(). I also can't find in the docs how to do this on multiple related entities like my human based query:

```
Get the entries WHERE  region is (1 or 2 or 3) AND type is ( 3 or 4 or 5 ) AND tag is (
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also consider taking a look at the D2 query builder.  Bit more verbose but it's much easier to build more complicated queries once you get the syntax down.

Something like:

```
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->addSelect('entry');
    $qb->addSelect('region');
    $qb->addSelect('type');
    $qb->addSelect('tag');

    $qb->from('MyBundle:Entry',   'entry');
    $qb->leftJoin('entry.regions','region');
    $qb->leftJoin('entry.types',  'type');
    $qb->leftJoin('entry.tags',   'tag');


    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('region.id',$regions));
    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('type.id',  $types));
    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('tag.id',   $tags));
```

Comment: This is much better than what I was doing, and you don't have to worry about sanitization.